# Mass reverse geocoding in Lightroom or an external tool

Tags: software, lightroom, geotagging, lightroom-4

I have nearly 3000 images in my Lightroom library that have GPS data but no textual location info. How can I mass reverse geocode all these pictures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeffrey Friedl's Geocoding plugin is excellent.   I have used it with Lightroom versions 3 and 4, but I believe it also works with version 2.    It supports bulk reverse-Geocoding and one-by-one geocoding (it can also work with GPS tracks and it integrates with Google Earth, but it sounds like you don't need those features).    It uses the Google Maps API to perform this.  Jeffrey also has a lot of other useful plugins too.   You can obtain them via the LR Plugin Manager (there is a market) or at Jeffrey's plugin website http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/gps